# React addons update() with $splice - how to insert an object into an array of objects?

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I have an array of objects represented by this.state.lanesData . How do I insert a new object into this array at position [lanes]? This is what i have so far, but I am getting the error

> Uncaught Error: Expected $splice target to be an array; got [object
>   Object]

```
        this.setState(
        update(this.state, {
            lanesData: {
                lanes: {
                    $splice: [
                        [dragIndex, 1],
                        [hoverIndex, 0, dragLane]
                    ],
                }
            }
        }));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.setState({
  lanesData: update(this.state.lanesData, {$splice: [[pos, lanes, newobj]]})
})
```